# JTable Cells Seem to resize without provocation

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a Jtable that is populated from hibernate.  All fields populate just fine though the table is inside of a jscrollpane.  I set the dbData.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize of the table like this:

```
dbData.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(dbData.getPreferredSize());

    dbScrollPane = new JScrollPane(null, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    dbScrollPane.getViewport().add(dbData);
    Universalvars.setUpdatePane(dbScrollPane);
    dbScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    dbScrollPane.setSize(750, 725);

    dbScrollPane.setLocation(25, 0);

    this.add(dbScrollPane);
```

Now after the table is populated with the data from hibernate and mysql I resize the width of every column which in turn makes it so that textAreas in blocks get longer there by needing less space for text in height.  After doing this action, the rows do not resize.

Now the table in question has 15 columns.  Only the first 7 are visible in the view ports and are 1 liner text blocks.  When I scroll over in the Jscrollpane to see the larger text block cells, thats when the table automatically grows the cells in height, though it still leaves the blank white space.

I Hope this makes sense as to post all the project code would probably be very excessive.  Anyway, is there a way to get it so that I can have the cells set at a certain width and the row heights to match what they should be to hold the right amount of text?  like if all columns have one line of text in the row I don't need it to be 200 px high, but the same goes for this, if there is a row that has one column having 500 characters of text and the cell is 300 px wide, then that whole row needs to be taller.  Though it does not need to have double or triple the amount of space necessary to accommodate said text.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getViewport().add(...)`, use `getViewport().setView(...)`

This is because a viewport conceptually controls a single view and does so in a special way.

Don't use `setSize` or `setLocation`, this suggestions the use of a `null` layout, which is going to cause problems when run on different systems, with different fonts and rendering pipelines.  Stick with the layout management API, it'll make life much simpler

**Updated**

First things first, don't modify the state of the table or model in anyway from within cell renderers, this will set of a serious of never ending updates.

Second, use a TableModelListener to monitor for changes to the state of the table and a TableColumnModelListener to monitor changes to the column model

When you detect a change in either of these, you need to probe the appropriate cell renderer(s) to determine their preferred size(s) and adjust the column/row size accordingly.

Just be sure, you're not making adjustments because of events raised because of your adjustments ;)

**Updated with example**

This is a really basic example to try and give a generally idea of how you might achieve this...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import static java.awt.Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class VariableTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new VariableTable();
    }

    private JTable table;
    private boolean ignoreUpdates;

    public VariableTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                table = new JTable(loadTableModel());
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new TextAreaRenderer());

                table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                        updateTableProperties();
                    }
                });
                table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                        updateTableProperties();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                        updateTableProperties();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                        updateTableProperties();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        updateTableProperties();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    }
                });

                updateTableProperties();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void updateTableProperties() {
        if (!ignoreUpdates) {
            ignoreUpdates = true;
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount() - 1; i++) {
                    adjustColumnSizes(i, 2);
                }
                adjustJTableRowSizes(2);
            } finally {
                ignoreUpdates = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void adjustJTableRowSizes(int column) {
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            int maxHeight = 0;
            TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            Object valueAt = table.getValueAt(row, column);
            Component tableCellRendererComponent = cellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, valueAt, false, false, row, column);

            DefaultTableColumnModel colModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel) table.getColumnModel();
            TableColumn tc = colModel.getColumn(column);

            int heightPreferable = tableCellRendererComponent.getPreferredSize().height;
            tableCellRendererComponent.setSize(tc.getWidth(), heightPreferable);
            heightPreferable = tableCellRendererComponent.getPreferredSize().height;

            maxHeight = Math.max(heightPreferable, maxHeight);
            table.setRowHeight(row, maxHeight);
        }

    }

    public void adjustColumnSizes(int column, int margin) {
        DefaultTableColumnModel colModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel) table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn col = colModel.getColumn(column);
        int width;

        TableCellRenderer renderer = col.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }
        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, col.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
        width = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

        for (int r = 0; r < table.getRowCount(); r++) {
            renderer = table.getCellRenderer(r, column);
            comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, table.getValueAt(r, column), false, false, r, column);
            int currentWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
            width = Math.max(width, currentWidth);
        }

        width += 2 * margin;

        col.setPreferredWidth(width);
        col.setWidth(width);
//        col.setMinWidth(width);
        col.setMaxWidth(width);
    }

    public TableModel loadTableModel() {

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                        new String[]{"Chapter", "Paragraph", "Text"}, 0);

        int chapter = 0;
        int paragraph = 0;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Book.txt")))) {

            String text = null;
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (text.startsWith("Chapter:")) {
                    chapter++;
                    paragraph = 0;
                } else if (text.trim().length() > 0) {
                    paragraph++;
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{
                        chapter,
                        paragraph,
                        text
                    });
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();;
        }

        return model;

    }

    public static class TextAreaRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {

        protected static Border NOT_SELECTED_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

        public TextAreaRenderer() {
            setLineWrap(true);
            setWrapStyleWord(true);
            this.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);
            setBorder(NOT_SELECTED_BORDER);
            setColumns(20);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                        boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setText(value.toString());

            if (table == null) {
                return this;
            }

            Color fg = null;
            Color bg = null;

            JTable.DropLocation dropLocation = table.getDropLocation();
            if (dropLocation != null
                            && !dropLocation.isInsertRow()
                            && !dropLocation.isInsertColumn()
                            && dropLocation.getRow() == row
                            && dropLocation.getColumn() == column) {

                fg = UIManager.getColor("Table.dropCellForeground");
                bg = UIManager.getColor("Table.dropCellBackground");

                isSelected = true;
            }

            if (isSelected) {
                setForeground(fg == null ? table.getSelectionForeground()
                                : fg);
                setBackground(bg == null ? table.getSelectionBackground()
                                : bg);
            } else {
                Color background = table.getBackground();
                if (background == null || background instanceof javax.swing.plaf.UIResource) {
                    Color alternateColor = UIManager.getColor("Table.alternateRowColor");
                    if (alternateColor != null && row % 2 != 0) {
                        background = alternateColor;
                    }
                }
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
                setBackground(background);
            }

            setFont(table.getFont());

            if (hasFocus) {
                Border border = null;
                if (isSelected) {
                    border = UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusSelectedCellHighlightBorder");
                }
                if (border == null) {
                    border = UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder");
                }
                setBorder(border);

                if (!isSelected && table.isCellEditable(row, column)) {
                    Color col;
                    col = UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellForeground");
                    if (col != null) {
                        super.setForeground(col);
                    }
                    col = UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellBackground");
                    if (col != null) {
                        super.setBackground(col);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                setBorder(NOT_SELECTED_BORDER);
            }

            return this;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Th. you're going to have to provide more information, possibly a runnable example each demonstrates your problem

Comment: What are is rendering the text? The default cell renderer?

Comment: I have posted 5 classes which I hope will illustrate things more and I am going to attempt to record the screen from the compilation

Comment: So is the cell renderer bad to use all together?

Comment: No, the idea of using it to display multi lines of text is correct, you just shouldn't modify the state of the table or model form within it

Comment: So how would I tell the rows how tall to be?  I'm guessing that I would have to remove all size changes front the text area renderer class, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You would need to use the `TableModelListener` and `ColumnModelListener` to detect changes that might effect the size of the cells and re-calculate each effect cell individually...

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  This is what I have right now:

Comment: I have the changeEvent firing, so at this point would I retire the cell renderer, or resize height with a custom function?

Comment: You should take the resizing code out of the cell renderer, you'll still need the renderer ;)

Comment: I know how to loop through all the cells in each row but how would I access the text area within the cell to see how tall it is with the text that it holds after the cell width change?

Comment: As per the example, get the cell render to grab a copy of the component and use it to determine what space it would like...

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getCellRenderer());
            if(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getCellRenderer() instanceof TextAreaRenderer) {
             System.out.println("blah");
             TextAreaRenderer tar = (TextAreaRenderer) table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getCellRenderer();
             System.out.println(tar.getText());
             System.out.println(tar.getSize().height);
            }
    }

Comment: Problem is, the value for text always returns blank, and the height is always returned as 0

Comment: Why do you want the text? It won't be applied until a individual cell is rendered

Comment: Oh I don't really want the text, I was just running some tests to see if I got values coming back.  The height shouldn't return as 0 though I wouldn't think.  That's where I'm kinda confused.

Comment: the getHeight() method also returns as 0

Comment: A component won't have a size until you apply one, as the example shows, you should be using the preferred size of the component

Comment: Okay, I tried that and it all returns a value of 16.  How am I to get large text areas to return their size?  Like say I have one row that has a cell containing word wrapped text of 300 characters that ends up being around 120 px high.  How would I retrieve that information?  Thank you.

Comment: Yep :), what I did was set the size of the renderer component, so that the width was the width of the column and the size was its preferred height, then looked at the preferred size again. This is neat trick of the text area

Comment: I'm looping through like this:

Comment: JTable table = Universalvars.getDocTable();
    for(int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
     for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
      if(table.get(row, i) instanceof TextAreaRenderer) {
       System.out.println("Cell TextAreaRenderer");
TextAreaRenderer tar = (TextAreaRenderer) table.get(row, i);       System.out.println(tar.getText());       System.out.println(tar.getSize().height);   System.out.println(tar.getHeight());  System.out.println(tar.getWidth());   System.out.println(tar.getPreferredSize().height);

Comment: System.out.println(tar.getPreferredSize().width);
       System.out.println(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getWidth());
       
       tar.setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getWidth(), tar.getPreferredSize().height);
       System.out.println(tar.getPreferredSize().height);
       System.out.println(tar.getPreferredSize().width);
      }
     }
    }

Comment: This is my output for my last cell, text is blank hence the blank space, though the actual text is several sentences long and the block is actually 300 px wide.  How do I get the height adjustment?
Cell TextAreaRenderer

16
16
125
16
125
300
16
300

Comment: Idiot moment.  Sorry about the confusion, I didn't see the sample loaded earlier for some reason.  Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: Say I'm still using this same application, and I add an entry into the database with the table we have been discussing using hibernate.  How would I update that table to show the new entry?

Comment: I can get the entry into the database just fine but the table update is the issue I'm having at this juncture.

Comment: Add the new entry to the table model, it will notify the table (and any other listeners) of the update